# Save temporary files to permanently so that the application can get it later on

Tags: python

Language: Python

Use the phonebook application code below. 
When I quit the application and restart it, all the numbers are lost. what code can i add so when the phonebook quits it saves all the name and phone number pairs out to a file with each name and number separated by a colon (:) and each record on separate lines. When the program first runs it should then look for that filename in the same directory and if it exists, read in all the data from that file into the dictionary.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

    phones = {}

    def menu():
        print("1. Add a record")
        print("2. Lookup a record")
        print("3. Update a record")
        print("4. Remove a record")
        print("5. List all records")
        print("6. Quit")
        selection = input("Please make your selection from the options above: ")
        if(selection == '1'):
          addRecord()
          menu()
        if(selection == '2'):
          lookupRecord()
          menu()
        if(selection == '3'):
          updateRecord()
          menu()
        if(selection == '4'):
          removeRecord()
          menu()
        if(selection == '5'):
          listRecords()
          menu()
        if(selection == '6'):
          quit()
        if selection != '1' or '2' or '3' or '4' or '5' or '6':
          print("Invalid Value, Try again")
          return menu()
        

    def addRecord():
        print("Add Name and Number")
        name = input("Name: ")
        if 'menu' == name.lower():
          print("-Name can't be used, Error: name registered by program as keyword")
          print("-Enter T to try again or M to go back to main menu")
          value = input("Enter Value: ")
          if 't' == value.lower():
            return addRecord()
          elif 'm' == value.lower():
            return menu()
          else:
            print("Invalid Value, Try again")
            return menu()
        else:
          phone = input("Number: ")
          phones[name] = phone
          print("Phone number added")

    def lookupRecord():
        print("Lookup Number")
        name = input("Name: ")
        if name in phones:
          print("Number Found")
          print("The number is", phones[name])
        else:
          print(name, "was not found")

    def updateRecord():
        print("Update Number")
        name = input("Name: ")
        for name in phones:
          print("Name found, Are you sure you want to update number")
          print("Enter Y if yes and N if no")
          value = input("Value: ")
          if "y" == value.lower():
            print("Enter new number")
            newNumber = input("Number: ")
            phones[name] = newNumber
            print("Phone number updated")
            return menu()
          elif "n" == value.lower():
            print("Didn't update number, returned to main menu")
            return menu()
        else:
          print("Name not found, Try again or type 'menu' to prompt to main menu")
          name = input("Name: ")
          if (name == "menu"):
            print(menu())

    def removeRecord():

        print("Remove Name and Number")
        name = input("Name: ")
        if name in phones:
          del phones[name]
          print("Phone number deleted")
        else:
          print(name, "was not found")

    def listRecords():

         print("Phone number recods:")
         for i in phones.keys():
           print("Name: ", i, "\tNumber:", phones[i])
           print()

    def quit():
      print("----session terminated----")
  


    def main():
        print("== Welcome to the Phonebook App ==")
        menu()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: A dictionary like `phones` only exists for the duration of the program's lifetime; when the program exits, that memory is lost along with any other variables you had during its execution. If you want persistent storage and state in your program, you might consider using a plaintext file to hold the numbers, or look into python's JSON library.

Comment: Another alternative is to use a persistent storage that looks and feels somewhat like regular Python objects, using the  `shelve` package. I have a patchy experience with it, but this is primarily because I use it in multiprocessing/multithreading environment. It will probably work pretty well for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

That should be quite quick to do in Python. First you'd need to write out your phone book just before exiting:

```
with open('phonebook.txt', 'w') as f:
    for name in phones:
        f.write(name, ':', phones[name], '\n')
```

Then, you'd need to read in all this when you start your program:

```
with open('phonebook.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data = line.split(':'):
            if len(data) != 2:
                # I'm assuming that there is no ':' in the name and phone number
                continue
            phones[data[0]] = data[1]
```

And that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for your specific ask:

```
import json
from pathlib import Path

ex_dict = {'user1': "678999999","user2":"678555555"}

def save_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
        for key, value in ex_dict.items():
            file.write(f"{key}:{value}\n")

save_file('file.txt')
```

`file.txt` now has:

```
user1:678999999
user2:678555555
```

To check and load it back in:

```
def load_file(file_path):
    # Looking for file.txt in current path
    file_path = Path(file_path)

    if file_path.exists():
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            lines = file.readlines()

            # Removes new line character /n from the lines
            lines = [x.rstrip() for x in lines] 
            return {line.split(":")[0]: line.split(":")[1] for line in lines} 

    else:
        return {}

loaded_dict = load_file("file.txt")
print(load_dict)
```

What is printed is:

```
{'user1': '678999999', 'user2': '678555555'}
```

Other methods I would recommend looking into is [JSON saving/loading](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html), [pickle](https://pythonprogramming.net/python-pickle-module-save-objects-serialization/), [pandas csv](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/saving-a-pandas-dataframe-as-a-csv/), and SQLite database. I'll give a quick example of the JSON one:

```
import json

data = {'user1': "678999999","user2":"678555555"}

# JSON save
with open('data.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(data, fp)


#JSON load
with open('data.json', 'r') as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)
```